# Visualising JSON data using python libraries

Tags: python, json, pandas, graph

I am visualising the json data using mathplotlib and pandas

```
  {
    "data_point": 0,
    "Add": 2977780,
    "Add_num": 38595
  },
  {
    "data_point": 1,
    "Add": 2809086,
    "Add_num": 36534
  },
  {
    "data_point": 2,
    "Add": 2825428,
    "Add_num": 36534
  },
  {
    "data_point": 3,
    "Add": 2826861,
    "Add_num": 36564
  }]
```

This is the data now i want to draw a graph with y-axis as value obtained from division of `"Add"` and `"Add_num"` (Add/Add_num) and `"data_point"` as x-axis. Is there a way to do this in python code or I need to process json data to add `Add_avg` field in json file(i.e. Add_avg = Add/Add_num)

Code to draw the graph

```
import json
import pandas as pd

a_file = open("./data.json", "r")
json_object = json.load(a_file)
a_file.close()
df = pd.DataFrame(json_object)
df.plot(x='data_point', y='Add',color='maroon', marker='o')
df.plot(x='data_point', y='Add_num',color='maroon', marker='o')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib` directly to plot, then you can do the calculations while plotting. Or you can indeed add another column:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

js = """[ {
    "data_point": 0,
    "Add": 2977780,
    "Add_num": 38595
  },
  {
    "data_point": 1,
    "Add": 2809086,
    "Add_num": 36534
  },
  {
    "data_point": 2,
    "Add": 2825428,
    "Add_num": 36534
  },
  {
    "data_point": 3,
    "Add": 2826861,
    "Add_num": 36564
  }]"""

# Use loads instead of load since in my case the json is a string:
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(js))

# plot:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(df['data_point'], df['Add']/df['Add_num'])
plt.show()
```

Or add a new column:

```py
df['Add_avg'] = df['Add']  / df['Add_num']
df.plot(x='data_point', y='Add_avg', color='maroon', marker='o')
plt.show()
```